# ajax autocomplete extender not showing results in different lines

Tags: c#, ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have a template in which i have added a textbox, autocomplete extender is working but the results are not coming in separate lines. Is there any specific code to do so?

Check image here

[image]

Comment: Show the code. Maybe you just set data source like a string not like a collection of strings.

Answer (score 0):

Code was proper. Data source was set to list only. I was using a master template because of which this was happening, I defined a separate css for autocompleteextender and it worked